# tagit tags are getting created as user presses down button to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I have used tagit plugin. I am using autocomplete feature and making an ajax call to fetch options. This is working good. But as user tries to select options, tags are getting created of each option. 
[image]
I have modified tagit js

```
focus: function(event, ui) {
           console.log(event);
           event.preventDefault();
           that.createTag(ui.item.label,ui.item.value);
}
```

so that, I can display label and use input value attribute as value of it.

```
e.g., label:Orange value:4
```

I want tags to be created only when user hits enter on option.

Comment: Try removing `that.createTag(ui.item.label,ui.item.value);`...

Comment: After removing, it is not creating tag